# Load file into array and check it with in_array

Tags: php, file

I want to check if a value exists in an array made from a text file. This is what I've got so far:

```
<?php
$array = file($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/textfile.txt');
if(in_array('value',$array)){
   echo 'value exists';
}
?>
```

I've experimented a little with foreach-loops as well, but couldn't find a way to do what I want.. The values in the text document are separated by new lines.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This happens because the lines of the file that become array values have a trailing newline. You need to use the `FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES` option of [file](http://ch2.php.net/manual/en/function.file.php) to get your code working as:

```
$array = file($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/textfile.txt',FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
```

**EDIT:**

You can use `var_dump($array)` and see that the lines have a newline at the end.

Comment: Oh, that explains a lot! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It should work like this. However, the `file()`method doesn't strip the newline characters from the file.

```
$array = file($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/textfile.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEWLINES);
```

Should do the trick. Check the [manual](http://ch2.php.net/manual/en/function.file.php) for file().

Answer (score 0):

```
$filename   = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/textfile.txt';
$handle     = fopen($filename, 'r');
$data       = fread($handle, filesize($filename));
$rowsArr    = explode('\n', $data);
foreach ($rowsArr as $row) {
    if ($row == 'value') {
        echo 'value exists';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to use an array? You could just use string comparison.

```
<?php
$string = file_get_contents('textfile.txt');
if(strpos($string, 'value')){
    echo 'value exists';
}else{
    echo 'value doesn\'t exist';
}
?>
```

Comment: Yeah, sort of. I want "accurate values", so an array would probably be best.

Comment: Then codaddict's answer fits you best. ;D